# Initial loading of angular2 reaches 3MB

Tags: angular

Initial loading of angular2 reaches 3MB.
I made a small application with the login and one crud and the initial loading takes too long. Takes about 10 seconds.

This is normal?
How to improve the initial loading angular 2?

The angular 2 has much dependence.(core.umd.js, platform-browser.umd.js, forms.umd.js, http.umd.js, ObjectUnsubscribedError.js... and various other!

[Print image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXMDI.png)

Comment: Are you using angular cli or webpack based project?

Comment: not. The webpack solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe the problem you have is the browser has to load a lot of files. If you concat js, version it, and minify it, you will reduce loading time. I would highly recommend using angular-cli.

Comment: are you getting many requests for rxjs files?

Comment: I'm calling -> import { Observable }    from 'rxjs/Observable', import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

Answer (score 2):

That's normal, by default Angular 2 loads a lot of stuff that acually you probably are not going to use with a simple "Hello World" application. But there is a solution for that. You can use tree shaking to optimize the size of your bundle.

Here can you find a very good article about this topic and how to proceed:
[Optimize your Angular 2 Application with Tree Shaking](http://blog.rangle.io/optimize-your-angular2-application-with-tree-shaking/). Or here as well: [Building an Angular 2 Application for Production](http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/).

Comment: I'm more relaxed knowing that it is normal. I hope the team angular improve the framework in this regard. I will follow your tips

Comment: Tree shaking is just one step that you can do to reduce your bundle size, but there are other steps that you can apply to even reduce more your bundle. For that, have a look at the second link I posted.